# How to solve a complicated equation system

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve the equation system `eq1==eq2`  for $\sigma1$  and $\sigma2$  where `eq1` and `eq2` are functions of 5 positive real variables as defined below:

```
eq1=(2 Sqrt[5 + 4 x1 + x1^2 + 2 y1 + y1^2])/(Sqrt[5] (2 + x1) (1 +y1))

eq2= (2 (1 + s) Sqrt[5 + 5 s^2 + 4 x1 σ1 + x1^2 σ1^2 + 2 y1 σ2 + y1^2 σ2^2 + 2 s (5 + 2 x1 σ1 + y1 σ2)])/(Sqrt[5] (2 + 2 s + x1 σ1) (1 + s + y1 σ2))
```

I am interested only in those solutions which are only a function of variable `s`. As a matter of fact I can simply verify that `s+1` is a solution:

```
eq2 /. {σ1 -> 1 + s, σ2 -> 1 + s} //FullSimplify[#, s > 0] &
```

however, I have not been able to find this solution using Mathematica.

I have tried the following

```
Reduce[eq1 == eq2 && 0 < x1 && 0 < y1 && 0 < σ1 &&0 < σ2 && 0 < s, {σ1, σ2},Reals] // FullSimplify
```

and

```
Solve[eq1 == eq2, {σ1, σ2}, Reals] // FullSimplify
```

but none of these result in the simple solution `s+1`. My question is what is the right approach to solving this kind of equations in Mathematica.

Answer (score 3):

`SolveAlways` might be the way to go. You are after relations between $\sigma1$, $\sigma2$ and $s$ which make the equation hold for all values of $x1$ and $y1$, so you would use:

```
SolveAlways[eq2 == eq1, {x1, y1}]
```

Unfortunately this seems very slow and I wasn't patient enough to let it finish. However, squaring both sides gives results quickly:

```
SolveAlways[eq2^2 == eq1^2, {x1, y1}] // DeleteDuplicates

(* {{σ1 -> 0, s -> -1}, {σ1 -> 1 + s, σ2 -> 1 + s}, {σ2 -> 0, s -> -1}} *)
```

Comment: Many thanks @Simon Woods. I am still running the first line to see if I get a solution.

Comment: You got any solution?